# Specify returnURL In QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, returnurl

This is probably a simple question but I am struggling with returnurl in a querystring. I know how to call the returnurl in a querystring into a Response.Redirect but I am not sure how to set the returnurl to a certain url. Can someone give me a example of how to do this?

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)

Comment: Little bit confusing, could you please be more specific

Comment: It would be weird that you would want to specify the return url in the backend, when it is the backend's job to respond to that return url request....

Comment: Hi Jamie, Can you provide bit more context. Like any code examples, and also framework? Are you using MVC, Asp Core, Web forms?

Comment: I have added an answer, based on what i understand  from the question. Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suggestion for you, I'm sure how much it is apt for your situation.

Let me define a Static `Dictionary<string,string>` to save some key and corresponding URLs. Since it is statically defined you can access it from all other pages, this variable will get application scope. ie.,

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> URLDictonary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                         {
                                          {"google","http://google.com/"}, 
                                          {"dotnet","http://www.dotnetperls.com/"},     
                                          {"querystring","http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring"}
                                         };
```

So that you can attach the `key` name with the URL as query string. It may look like the following:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Somepage.aspx?returnURL=google");
// Which means you are passing the key as query string
```

Now you can get this `key` in sample page and redirect to the specific page based on the key as follows:

```
string returnURL = Request.QueryString["returnURL"];
if (returnURL != null)
{
    Response.Redirect(URLDictonary[returnURL]);
}
```

Since we are passing `google` it will redirect to the corresponding value ie. `"http://google.com/"`.

**Note :**  You can create similar Dictionary with  your own keys and Urls. If it is defined in a different class then use `class_name.DictonaryName[querystring_value]`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in the following:

```
var url = Request.Url.ToString();
var uri = String.Format("http://example.com?page={0}", url);
Response.Redirect(uri);
```

The code is pretty straight forward.

Comment: You will want to encode url before doing this to make sure that special characters are dealt with correctly.